# Why am I getting this ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, syntax-error

```py
def convert_seconds(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds - hours * 3600) // 60
    remaining_seconds = seconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60
    return hours, minutes, seconds, remaining_seconds

hours, minutes, seconds = convert_seconds(5000)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, you are `return`ing 4 variables and unpacking 3. `return hours, minutes, seconds, remaining_seconds` vs `hours, minutes, seconds = convert_seconds(5000)`. Where should `remaining_seconds` go?

Answer (score 1):

The function returns four variables...

```
return hours, minutes, seconds, remaining_seconds
```

... but then you only fetch three of those values:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = convert_seconds(5000)
```

Comment: I see the error now. I mistakenly added an extra word to the last line as you said. I never put the remaining_seconds after that

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all values when unpacking:

```
def convert_seconds(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds - hours * 3600) // 60
    remaining_seconds = seconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60
    return hours, minutes, seconds, remaining_seconds

hours, minutes, seconds, remaining_seconds = convert_seconds(5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns **4** values: hours, minutes, seconds, remaining_seconds

In your function call you are unpacking **3** values: hours, minutes, seconds

So you have too many values to unpack, the correct would be to unpack 4 values:

`hours, minutes, seconds, remaining_seconds = convert_seconds(5000)`